# Highcharts dual axis set yRange

Tags: range, axis, highcharts

I am having some trouble to set the range of my dual axis on the highcharts. The first y-axis has to be in the range [-5,40]. The second one has to be in [0,80]. I tried to do it but it with `tickInterval` or setting the `min` and the `max`, but it doesn't seems to work. How can I do it?

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/erifel/t0775Luo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways to achieve that.

Disable [Chart.alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.alignTicks) and [start/endOnTick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick).

```
yAxis: [{
  min: -5,
  max: 40.0,
  //    tickInterval: 11.25,
  //   tickPositions: [-5, 6.25, 17.5, 28.75, 40],
  title: {
    text: 'TEMP (Celsius)'
  },
  endOnTick: false,
  startOnTick: false
  }, {
  endOnTick: false,
  startOnTick: false,
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  tickInterval: 20,
  min: 0,
  max: 80,
  title: {
    text: 'UMID (%)'
  },
  opposite: true
}],
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/t0775Luo/7/

Control ticks via [tickPositions/tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions)

```
yAxis: [{
  min: -5,
  max: 40.0,
  tickPositions: [-5, 6.25, 17.5, 28.75, 40],
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/t0775Luo/10/

Answer (score 0):

First, set `alignTicks: false` on the chart object.

Then, set a `tickInterval` that works with your min and max:

```
yAxis: [{
  min: -5,
  max: 40.0,
  tickInterval: 15
},{
  min: 0,
  max: 80,
  tickInterval: 20
}]
```

Updated fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/t0775Luo/9/